# Number-theoretic asymptotic looks false but is true?

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, asymptotics, chebyshev-function

### Question

Let $p_r$ be the $r'th$ prime. Is it true that,

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r \ln(p_r) \sim \frac{s}{(1-s)} $$

I know this looks bizarre but kindly consider the argument below. I'm also interested in knowing if this technique (of summing to simplify via asymptotics) is known?

### Argument

I recently observed an interesting behavior of the following series:

$$ K(s) = s \ln(2) + s^2 \ln(3) + s^3 \ln(5)+ \dots  = \sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r \ln(p_r)$$

where $p_r$ is the $r'th$ prime

$$ \implies \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{r=0}^n s^r K(s) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r \ln(\# p_r)$$

where $\# p_r = 2 \times 3 \times \dots \times p_r$

$$ \frac{K(s)}{1-s} \sim \sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r r = \frac{s}{(1-s)^2}$$

Where $s \nearrow 1$

$$ \implies  K(s) \sim \frac{s}{(1-s)}$$

Comment: What does that formula even mean? It has the form $f(s) \sim g(s)$, which doesn't make sense by itself. You have to say $f(s) \sim g(s)$ as $s \to \infty$, or some such. But $\infty$ doesn't work here. So what _do_ you mean?

Comment: @TonyK I'm trying to make it analytically continuous and assigning it a value ...

Comment: So that $\sim$ should be an equal sign $=$?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use the $=$ sign because there would be some error terms.I'm using the relation given in: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevFunctions.html

Comment: @TonyK Asymptotic equality as $s \nearrow 1$, I think.

Comment: Just before `summary', I think you are assuming that if $a_n \sim n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n s^n \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty ns^n = s/(1-s)^2$. Is this true?

Comment: @MarkWildon Well I think so ... 
 $ \sum s^r = \frac{1}{1-s} \implies \sum r s^{r-1} = \frac{1}{(1-s)^2} \implies \sum s^r = \frac{s}{(1-s)^2} $

Comment: @DanielFischer what does $s \nearrow 1$ mean? (I'm only expecting a reference and I've only done a first course in asymptotics)

Comment: It means "$s$ approaches $1$ from below". Other frequent notations are $s\uparrow 1$ or $s \to 1^-$.

Comment: @MarkWildon, Yes, that's true.

Comment: @MarkWildon I wrote up some notes on it a while back: [pdf link](http://mathstat.dal.ca/~antoniov/notes/boundaryasymp.pdf). I haven't checked them recently so I apologize if there are any typos.