# Asymptotic relation for the following series?

Tags: number-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, prime-numbers, asymptotics

### Questions

Is the asymptotic relationship correct? How do I determine $c_1$ and $\kappa$? As, $|s| \to 0$

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r \ln(r) \sim c_1 \sqrt{s} + (\kappa - 1 + \frac{\ln(2 \pi)}{2} )s$$

Is it possible to find $A_r$ using this relationship (for any of the r's)? Where,

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty A_r(s) \ln(p_r) \sim c_1 \sqrt{s} + (\kappa - 1 + \frac{\ln(2 \pi)}{2} )s$$

### Background

Recently I found a technique as in a previous question: [Number-theoretic asymptotic looks false but is true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626615/number-theoretic-asymptotic-looks-false-but-is-true)

This led me to another series with interesting properties:

$$ K(s) = s \ln 1 + s^2 \ln 2 + s^3 \ln 3 +  \dots  =  \sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r \ln(r) $$

$$ \implies K(s) =  A_1(s) \ln 2 + A_2(s) \ln(3) + A_3(s) \ln 5 + \dots = \sum_{r=1}^\infty A_r(s) \ln(p_r) $$

Where $p_r$ is the r'th prime

Now consider the following:

$$ K(s) =  \sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r \ln(r) $$
$$ \implies \sum_{r=0}^\infty s^r K(s) = s \ln 1! + s^2 \ln 2! + s^3 \ln 3! + \dots $$
$$ \implies \frac{ K(s)}{1-s} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r \ln r! $$

Using Stirling approximation:

$$ \implies \frac{ K(s)}{1-s} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r (r \ln(r) - r +\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi) + \frac{1}{2} \ln r + \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k/r^k)  $$

where $a_n$ is the coefficients of the $1/r$ error terms

$$ \implies \frac{ K(s)}{1-s} = s \frac{dK}{ds} - \frac{s}{(1-s)^2} + \frac{\ln(2 \pi) s }{2(1-s)} + \frac{K}{2} + a_1 \text{Li}_1(s)  + a_2 \text{Li}_2(s)\dots $$

where $\text{Li}_r(s)$ is the $r$'th poly-logarithmic function.
Taking $|s| \to 0 $ and using the asymptotic relation of $\text{Li}_r(s) \sim s$

$$ \implies \frac{ K(s)}{2} \sim s \frac{dK}{ds} - s + \frac{\ln(2 \pi) s }{2} +  \kappa s $$

whre $\kappa= \sum a_r$ and now solving the differential equation:

$$ K(s) \sim c_1 \sqrt{s} + (\kappa - 1 + \frac{\ln(2 \pi)}{2} )s$$

Comment: By "$s \nearrow 0$" do you mean that $s$ approaches $0$ from below, i.e. from the negative side?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I'm sorry at the time I must have been completely exhausted however I have completely re-edited the question.

Comment: In what sense do you mean "$\sim$"? As $s \to 0$ the sum $\sum_{r=1}^\infty s^r \ln(r)$ behaves like $\ln(2) s^2$, and as $s \to 1^-$ it behaves like $\ln(-\ln(s))/(s-1)$, so I don't really see where you're coming from.

Comment: I mean $\sim$ as $s \to 0$ Besides that please let me know which part of my background (justification) is unclear? (so that way I can improve that) And **I think** my asymptotic relationship should be more powerful

Comment: Please read my comment more carefully. I told you what the correct asymptotic is as $|s| \to 0$. The asymptotic in your question is incorrect.

Comment: Ah ... thank you and sorry about that ... Can you tell me where I've gone wrong in my background so I could learn from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series

$$
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} s^r \ln(r) = s^2 \ln(2) + s^3 \ln(3) + \cdots
$$

is, in fact, an [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion#Formal_Definition) with respect to the asymptotic scale $\{s^r\}_{r\in\mathbb N}$ as $s \to 0$. In particular, *it is its own asymptotic expansion as $s \to 0$*. Proving this would be a very valuable exercise if it is not immediately obvious.

One particular consequence of this fact is that

$$
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} s^r \ln(r) = s^2 \ln(2) + O(s^3) \qquad \text{as } s \to 0, \tag{$*$}
$$

so it can't possibly be true that an asymptotic for the series includes a term involving $\sqrt{s}$ since that would violate $(*)$. *No terms which decay more slowly than $s^2$ may appear in an asymptotic for the series unless they are cancelled out by some other term.*

Now, to try to address your proposed derivation:

I'm not an expert in the polylogs, but you might want to be more careful "solving" an "asymptotic differential equation". Making something like that rigorous is difficult because there are so many cases where doing that gives you the wrong answer. Assuming what you've done prior to that step is correct, that must be where your error lies. You have found an example where "solving" an "asymptotic differential equation" gives you nonsense.

Comment: Also in one of the comments you said as $s \to 1^{-}$ it behaves as $ \ln(-\ln(s))/(s-1)$ out of curiosity how did you get that?

Comment: @AnantSaxena, Try comparing your series to an integral. Often $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) \approx \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$, and in your case this is true. The full justification is too long for a comment though, so I would suggest posting another question to ask about it. I'm sure someone can give you a good answer.